# How to correctly uninstall Ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9

Hi:) I have manually set Ruby 1.9.1. I have installed it via

```
./configure --prefix=/opt
make
make install
```

The target 'uninstall' does not exist in generated Makefile ...
How to do uninstallation **correctly?**

PS: I also believe that it is necessary to remove all the gems.
For this I use

```
#!/bin/sh
gem list --local | grep [^\*] | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs gem uninstall
```

Comment: You'll get better results from superuser.com, I think.

Comment: Use rvm for this, save yourself weeks of pain. http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with another software installed in `/opt`. I solved the issue by

1. creating an empty directory elsewhere (like `/tmp/ruby`)
2. installing exactly the same version you want to remove in this directory
3. printing a list of all files in the new location, replacing`/tmp/ruby` with `/opt`.
4. erasing the resulting list

On unix, you can first try:

```
$ find /tmp/ruby | sed "s/\/tmp\/ruby\//\/opt\//"
```

Look carefully at the list, if it seems valid, use:

```
$ find /tmp/ruby | sed "s/\/tmp\/ruby\//\/opt\//" | xargs rm
```

To really remove the files...